# Iterate over JSON and print values in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am quite new to Vue and am attempting to retrieve a JSON response from an API and then print this on my page.

This is what I have so far:

```
<body>
    <div id="mystats" class="container">
    <h1>My Top Tracks</h1>

    <ol>
        <li v-for="track in tracks">@{{ track.name }}</li>
    </ol>
    <pre>@{{ tracks|json }}</pre>
    <button v-on:click="fetchStats">Fetch stats</button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.3/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.0.3/vue-resource.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $vue = new Vue({
            el: '#mystats',

            data: {

                tracks: [],

            },

            methods: {
                fetchStats: function()
                {
                   this.$http.get('/mystatsdata', {params:  {type: 'tracks'}}).then((response) => {
                    this.tracks.push(response.body);
                    console.log(this.tracks.name);
                  }, (response) => {
                    // error callback
                  }); 
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

Below is the response I am getting back:

```
[
  [
    {
      "name": "Falling Away - Acoustic (Bonus Track)",
      "track_number": 8,
      "type": "track",
    }
  ]
]
```

The issue is that the:

```
<ol>
    <li v-for="track in tracks">@{{ track.name }}</li>
</ol>
```

is not printing out the track name.

There's no error in my console, and so being a little new to Javascript and Vue.js I'm not really sure where I am going wrong.

How do I get the name to display?

**Edit**

Here is the response with more than one entry (limited to 2 currently):

```
[
  [
    {
      "name": "Falling Away - Acoustic (Bonus Track)",
      "track_number": 8,
      "type": "track",
    },
    {
      "name": "Perfect Strangers",
      "track_number": 1,
      "type": "track",
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: You are receiving an array of arrays of objects. Could you show how it returns two result?

Comment: @craig_h have added another

Comment: @craig_h that worked, however only returned one result, when it should return two. i.e there are two tracks in the response and only the first gets displayed.

Comment: If you swap out the production version (`vue.min.js`) for the development version (`vue.js`) it might give you a warning or error message.

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle to show you what you should be aiming for: https://jsfiddle.net/kn1arbem/

Comment: @craig_h The issue is I am using a Laravel backend to query an external API currently - so I can't alter the format without reformatting it myself.

Comment: You should be able to quickly `json decode` it then get your information and then `json_encode` it in your controller, otherwise you can just use `v-for="track in tracks[0]"`: https://jsfiddle.net/kn1arbem/1/

Comment: @craig_h using `v-for="track in tracks[0]"` has worked. It looks like the Spotify API I am querying returns an array with all the tracks, and then when I am using `this.tracks.push(response.body);` it is wrapping it inside the pre-defined tracks array. Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The response that you are getting back is an array containing another array - which in turn contains the actual objects representing your tracks.

So inside: `<li v-for="track in tracks">@{{ track.name }}</li>` , the `track` refers to the inside array and not to each object.

For quick-fix, you can change your code to:

`<li v-for="track in tracks[0]">@{{ track.name }}</li>`

and try.

But the proper fix would be to fix the backend, to return the result as a single array of objects.

Comment: Thanks, using `v-for="track in tracks[0]"` has worked. It looks like the Spotify API I am querying returns an array with all the tracks, and then when I am using `this.tracks.push(response.body);` it is wrapping it inside the pre-defined tracks array. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Instead of doing `this.tracks.push(response.body)`, as the response *is* the list of tracks, why not use `this.tracks = response.body` ?

Answer (score 3):

As @craig_h suggested it looks like you're receiving an array of array of objects instead of an array of objects.

I would recommand you to send a better formatted json like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Falling Away - Acoustic (Bonus Track)",
    "track_number": 8,
    "type": "track",
  },
  {
    "name": "Falling Away2 - Acoustic (Bonus Track)",
    "track_number": 9
    "type": "track",
  }
]
```

If you don't have access to the backend, using `this.tracks.push(response.body[0])` in your fetchStats method should do the trick.

Comment: Using `this.tracks.push(response.body[0])` cuts out the second result?

Comment: If `response.body` is the json you provided, you should get exactly the json in my answer with `response.body[0]`, so the second result should be there ;)